# How to properly call a command from Makefile that has a variable substituted

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
SOURCE_myfile=/opt
SOURCE_myfile2=/usr/lib
all:

    for i in {myfile,myfile2}; do  echo $${SOURCE_$$i};  done
```

My need: to print content of the two variables `SOURCE_myfile` and `SOURCE_myfile2`, but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
% make
for i in {myfile,myfile2}; do  echo ${SOURCE_$i};  done
/bin/sh: ${SOURCE_$i}: bad substitution
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that for-loop syntax is not valid POSIX syntax.  It may work in bash (although it's not needed there) but make always invokes `/bin/sh` and that is not always bash.  You want to just use: `for i in myfile myfile2; do ...`

Second, you can't combine shell operations and make variables like this: there's no ongoing interaction between the shell, which is running the loop, and the makefile.  Make will fully expand the recipe so that all make constructs no longer exist in the result, then send the result to the shell and the shell will run everything.

It's really unclear what the parameters are around your request but one way to do it would be this:

```
for i in '$(SOURCE_myfile)' '$(SOURCE_myfile2)'; do echo $$i; done
```

Almost certainly that doesn't help you because your actual needs are different but you haven't explained them so...

Comment: Thanks. My need is to print content of the two variables SOURCE_myfile and SOURCE_myfile2

Comment: Then why not just use `echo $(SOURCE_myfile) $(SOURCE_myfile2)` ?  What's with the loop?

Comment: Well, there's a requirement that you didn't state earlier: this is exactly the kind of thing I meant when I said "what the parameters are around your request".  Above you said _the TWO variables_ so there's no point in doing anything more sophisticated than a simple echo.  Now we learn that actually you have a LOT of variables, in which case it may be simpler to do something else.  Do you have a list of these variable names anywhere?  Do they all have the same name format (e.g., do they all start with `SOURCE_` for example)?  If you tell us what your **actual requirements** are we can help.